# How to remove the app from play store? If it is removed, will it be removed from Mobile which is already installed?

Tags: android, mobile, google-play, mobile-application

I am a mobile developer working as a freelancer. My client wants to end with the business with me So, I decided to remove the app from the play store.

If I removed the app from play store, will it be removed from Mobile which is already installed?

I want to remove the app from all device which is already installed.

Answer (score 1):

To make your app invisible for downloading you have to unpublish it.If you unpublish the app the previous users still be able to use the app until they uninstall.

Comment: Correct. Moreover, is that what the client wants? Explain that it's not possible. What you could do is if you (hopefully) have a kill switch, then make the app unusable so those who already installed it can't use it. Or break all the endpoints ‍♂️

Comment: Looks like you don't want your users to use it.update the app with some crashes in the main activity itself and users don't like to keep the app that crash.They simply uninstall in a day or two.

Comment: After a long conversation with the client, he confesses not to remove the app from the play store.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove your app from google play console by unpublish it. After that,  users will no longer be able to download your app.

**But** - if some device already has your app installed it won't get deleted, it will stay on the device unless the user chooses to remove it from the actual device.